# Как запустить службу автоматически, когда запускается Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, django

Я использую Ubuntu 16 и хочу запустить сервис.
Сервис должны запускаться автоматически, когда система запускается. Сервис запускает django сервер.

```
[Unit]
Description=service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/ubuntu/wiki/Backend/manage.py python runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
Type=simple
```

В консоли ошибка:

```
● wiki.service - service

 Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/wiki.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)

 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-09-22 11:10:44 UTC; 3min 36s ago

 Main PID: 1144 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

systemd[1]:Started service.

python[1144]:Traceback (most recent call last):

python[1144]:File "/home/ubuntu/wiki/Backend/manage.py", line 17, in <module>

python[1144]: ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

systemd[1]: wiki.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

systemd[1]: wiki.service: Unit entered failed state.

systemd[1]: wiki.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: А как вы запускаете django сервер без сервиса?

Comment: @andreymal, запускаю командой python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

Comment: Написано, что не может импортировать Django.
(Скорее всего, ваш кэп).

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Дайте вывод запуска команды `/usr/bin/python /home/ubuntu/wiki/Backend/manage.py python runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот тут лишнее слово

ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/ubuntu/wiki/Backend/manage.py **python** runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

Потом хорошо бы перейти в каталог с проектом. Чтоб можно было продолжить разработку и не мучать себя с правами доступа, укажите имя пользователя и группу. Добавьте строчки

```
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/wiki/Backend/
User=Юзернайм
Group=Юзернайм
```

Ну и некрасиво, добавьте описание

```
Description=service
```